# Custom material properties in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

There are all these material properties that you can modify in OpenGL — things like shininess and diffuse-ness, etc. I was wondering if it's possible to create a custom material. Like, let's say I wanted to apply Perlin noise to materials proportional to the "static-iness" property. Is it possible for me to declare and define such a property on a per-material basis?

In particular, I want to be able to define rendering for that material in the vertex and fragment shaders for GLSL (preferably 120).

Comment: Those material properties are all for the fixed-function pipeline, by the way. They exist in GLSL as a carry-over, basically. In GLSL 1.50+, you have to declare your shader's version as: `#version 150 compatibility` just to use them. So in short, this is all possible, and you should stop thinking in terms of properties that GL defines and instead define your own custom properties per-material (e.g. as `uniform` or sometimes even `attribute` / `in`).

Comment: Oh. That was super easy. If you'll put that as an answer, I'll upvote you and accept. Thanks! =D